# Adding just chapter label and number, without the title

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titletoc

I am trying to create the following ToC with [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package:

```
Chapter 1 ..........  1

Chapter 2 .......... 10

Chapter 3 .......... 20
```

The `titletoc` code is the following:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0.5cm] % Indentation
  {\addvspace{5pt}\sc} % Spacing and font options for chapters
  {\contentslabel[\large\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{0.5cm}} % Chapter number
  {}
  {\normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage} % Page number
```

and for making the chapter I just use the command:

```
\chapter{}
```

The problem is that I see the dotted lines over the chapter x label. In other words, the dotted lines do not start when the the "chapter x" label finish, but they start at the same point (beginning of the line).

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: and you can do this without `titletoc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to provide enough space for the additional content that forms part of `\contentslabel` to fit, but also adjust the indentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}[25mm] % Indentation
  {\addvspace{5pt}} % Spacing options for chapters
  {\contentslabel[\scshape\large\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{25mm}} % Chapter number
  {}
  {\normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage} % Page number

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\chapter{}

\end{document}
```

Above the `\chapter`-related spacing is given as `25mm`, while the `\contentslabel` is given a similar `25mm` spacing. One could calculate this distance a little more precisely, but it doesn't seem to require that.

---

If you want to avoid using [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc), you can patch some chapter-related macros to achieve a similarly-looking result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\numberline{\thechapter}}% <search>
  {{\normalfont\scshape\large\@chapapp~\thechapter}~}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
% Remove bold formatting of chapters in ToC
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\bfseries}{}{}{}
% Add dotted ToC line for chapter entries in ToC
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\hfil}% <search>
  {\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\chapter{}

\end{document}
```

The above separation between dots are given by the *value* in the `\@dotsep` *macro*, which defaults to `4.5` (mu). To obtain something similar to the `titletoc` dotted rule, use the following patch instead:

```
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\hfil}% <search>
  {\leaders\hbox{\makebox[5pt]{.}}\hfill}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```